# Make method that returns when JButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I need to make a method that returns only when a `JButton` is pressed. I have a custom `JButton` class

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {


   public void waitForPress() {
       //returns only when user presses this button
   }

}
```

and I want to implement `waitForPress`. Basically, the method should only return when the user presses the button with their mouse. I have achieved similar behavior for `JTextField` (to return only when user presses `Space`):

```
public void waitForTriggerKey() {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        System.out.println("presed!");
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
            try {
                //current thread waits here until countDown() is called (see a few lines above)
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);

    }
```

but I would like to do the same thing with `JButton`.

***In advance:*** Please, if you wish to comment saying that this is not a good idea and that one should simply wait for `actionPerformed` event on a `JButton` and then do some action, please realize I already know that and have a good reason for doing what I'm asking here. Please try to only help with what I've asked. Thanks!!

***In advance:*** Please, also realize that implementing actionPerformed also will not directly solve the problem. Because the code will progress even without the button being pressed. I need the program to stop, and only return when the button has been pressed. Here is a terrible solution if I were to use actionPerformed:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionPerformed {
   private boolean keepGoing = true;

   public MyButton(String s) {
       super(s);
       addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void waitForPress() {
       while(keepGoing);
       return;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       keepGoing = false;
   }

}
```

Comment: My first instinct tells me that you should implement an `ActionListener`...

Comment: Yes however that does not achieve the goal as stated in the question. I need a function which RETURNS only on the button being pressed.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is: 1) you init your UI and show it to the user. 2) when the user presses a button you go on and do whatever is needed. The fact that those two actions may occur in different Threads should not matter

Comment: You can always use a modal `JDialog` which is a blocking call.

Comment: Please review the question. I understand Java quite well and know exactly what I'm doing. I want to achieve code structure as I have defined in the question...not the typical steps you just wrote.

Comment: Specifically, take a look at the example with JTextField and understand that it is possible to do with a Text Field. There must be a way to do this in JButton, I just do not know the event dispatch classes to use.

Comment: You could use a mutex which blocks as long as actionPerformed is not called. Would IMHO be better (cpu wise) than a while...

Comment: @CodeGuy: Using a modal JDialog seems what you are looking for. Yet, I strongly feel that this an inadequate design and that there is a problem in your current code.

Comment: Again, let me repeat @GuillaumePolet. I am fully aware of the potential problem here and know exactly what I'm doing. Please don't be too focused on the "design" and just focus on the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Burkhard Can you post code for a "mutex"? I don't know what this is.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet can you post how I could achieve this with a JDialog without having any pop ups?

Comment: @CodeGuy _I am fully aware of the potential problem here and know exactly what I'm doing_ I have been working with UI's and especially with Swing UI's for a while, I must say that I put some doubt in that latter statement (no offence). I don't see how you can't break your code into 2 methods and call the second one when the button is pressed. Anyway (and sorry about that) but if you feel that you should still pursue in that idea/design, I can't help you unfortunately.

Comment: is your only problem with using the `ActionListener` the busy wait or is there sth. else?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I do not want to get into a battle over experience, but I can assure you I have many many years of UI experience and there is a good reason for what I am doing. I still don't think you have reviewed my JTextField example. Please do so and realize how "doable" this task is and how concise a solution is.

Comment: @Zhedar my problem is that I don't have a solution the question I asked :)

Comment: @CodeGuy I don't want to go into experience battles either (and yes I read you Jtextfield example). So two things can happen here: 1) A different `Thread` than the EDT is invoking `waitForProcess()` and then, all you need is to invoke `wait()` and have an `ActionListener` that calls `notify()` (that is only basic Java Thread synchronization). 2) You are calling `waitForProcess()` from the EDT (and then I refer to my previous statement: split your code into 2 methods and call the second one in the `actionPerformed()`)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Okay, perfect. How can I set that up? Can you show me how to do this notify() and waitForProcess() stuff? Can you do that by showing the full implementation of waitForPress() ?

Comment: @CodeGuy See my answer below although you seem to have found an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked for an implementation with a mutex, here's what it would be like.
I'm using an `ActionListener` though, but there's no busy wait in it. If that isn't what you desire, you atleast saw what Burkhard meant ;)

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

    public MyButton(String text) throws InterruptedException
    {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(this);
        sem.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sem.release();
    }

    public void waitForPress() throws InterruptedException {
        sem.acquire();
        //do your stuff
        sem.acquire();
        //or just
        //waitForPress()
            //if you dont want it to end.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyButton m = new MyButton("test");
        frame.add(m);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        m.waitForPress();
        //another time, if you only want it to block twice
        m.waitForPress();
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is a clean approach, but it doesn't consume CPU-time like a while(isStatementTrue)-implementation.
An important thing here is: you're blocking the main thread with `m.waitForPress()` but as you wrote you're quite experienced and you know how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't tried it yet because I'm not sure what the "//do your stuff" part is? I just want the function to return when the button has been pressed. that's all the function does.

Comment: Please remove that `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));` call. This is just a very bad bad practice.

Comment: well, thats just a minimal working example. I dont do that normally. But I think I will better remove it.

Comment: @CodeGuy //do your stuff is code that would be executed, when the block ends. if you dont want that, just leave it. `sem.aquire()` will block and return when the button is pressed.

Comment: @Zhedar PERFECT!!! you've solved the answer. Thanks so much. Also, Guillaume Polet, thanks for your considerations and help as well.

Comment: @Zhedar: That's what I meant with mutex! Had no time till now to give an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here is how you can do it with `wait()` and `notify()` but yet I feel that there is a deeper problem here. I would not consider this as a satisfying solution:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestBlockingButton {

    boolean clicked = false;
    private Object toNotify;

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestBlockingButton.class.getSimpleName());
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clicked = true;
                if (toNotify != null) {
                    synchronized (TestBlockingButton.this) {
                        toNotify.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void waitForProcess() {
        toNotify = this;
        while (!clicked) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("continuing work");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TestBlockingButton test = new TestBlockingButton();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                test.initUI();
            }
        });
        ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("I was doing something and now I will wait for button click");
                test.waitForProcess();
                System.out.println("User has now cliked the button and I can continue my work");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Good learning example. However, I had to give the answer above since it worked fine.