# How to handle Submit button of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a problem, I have been making a Swing application.

My question is about how to handle `Jbutton` like a `JOptionPane`, if it's possible?

I want handle all of the buttons similarly to `JOptionpane` button, but our message written in main function `System.out.println("this line executes...how to prevent..");` 
This function is to display the message, until `Jframe` is visible.

Can anyone let me know how to prevent & how to handle button functionality? Especially when it executes further when I click the button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InputVerifierExample extends JPanel {
   public static final Color WARNING_COLOR = Color.red;
   private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField middleNameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField lastNameField = new JTextField(10);
   JLabel name=new JLabel("Name:");
   private JTextField[] nameFields = { 
         firstNameField, 
         middleNameField,
         lastNameField };
   private JLabel warningLabel = new JLabel("  ");

   public InputVerifierExample() {
      warningLabel.setOpaque(false);

      JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
      namePanel.add(name);
      MyInputVerifier verifier = new MyInputVerifier();
      for (JTextField field : nameFields) {
         field.setInputVerifier(verifier);
         namePanel.add(field);
      }
      namePanel.add(new JButton(new SubmitBtnAction()));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(namePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      warningLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
      add(warningLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

   private class SubmitBtnAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SubmitBtnAction() {
         super("Submit");
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // first check all fields aren't empty
         for (JTextField field : nameFields) {
            if (field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
               return ;  // return if empty
            }
         }
         String name = "";
         for (JTextField field : nameFields) {
            name += field.getText() + " ";
            field.setText("");
         }
         name = name.trim();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InputVerifierExample.this, name, "Name Entered",
               JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }
   }

   private class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

      @Override
      public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
         JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
         if (field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            warningLabel.setText("Please do not leave this field empty :"+name.getText());
            warningLabel.setBackground(WARNING_COLOR);
            //firstNameField.setText("sorry");
            return false;
         }
         warningLabel.setText("");
         warningLabel.setBackground(null);
         return true;
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputVerifier Example");
      frame.setSize(200, 500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new InputVerifierExample());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
            createAndShowGui();
      System.out.println("this line executes...how to prevent..");
   }

}
```

Comment: This is absolutely incomprehensible question. Try to reformulate it.

Comment: i want asking, System.out.println("this line executes...how to prevent.."); this line execute only when click submit button, like Joptionpane's function,

Comment: have u any ans. pls let me know.. i m working on some project its urgent.please

Comment: @user1936089 this is simply not how GUI works. To the exception of modal dialogs, GUI are asynchronous and work with callbacks (listeners) such as `ActionListener`, `MouseListener`, etc... Don't try to make a Swing GUI synchronous this will bring more problems than solutions.

Comment: have u any example send me..

Comment: @user1936089 If you want some line to be executed when a button is pressed, simply put that line inside an ActionListener.actionPerformed and add the listener to the button. There are tons of examples on SO.

Comment: @user1936089 have u seen my EG ?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  _"To the exception of modal dialogs, GUI are asynchronous and work with callbacks (listeners) such as ActionListener, MouseListener, etc... Don't try to make a Swing GUI synchronous this will bring more problems than solutions."_ +1

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestButton {

    protected void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestButton().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
        System.err.println("Executed once the button has been clicked");
    }

}
```

And you want the line `System.err.println("Executed once the button has been clicked");` to be executed when the button is pressed (which is not the case here above).

The solution is actually very simple: you move the code to execute after the button click in another method (see below the  `proceed()` method) and you invoke that line from an `ActionListener`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestButton {

    protected void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                proceed();
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void proceed() {
        System.err.println("Executed once the button has been clicked");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestButton().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: But can we do something like what OP has asked for?First I thought its silly, but have eaten my brains off.

Comment: To Check the functionality showMessageDialog() of JOptionPane i wants as it is. let suppose after wrote 100line after this function while messageDialog is visible on the screen further all line does't execute, till wait ok or cancel button pressing,

Comment: @user1936089 I don't know how I can make you "get it" but this is not how GUI work. I have shown you how you can modify your code to reach the exact behaviour you describe (in terms of functionality). If you really want, you can use `Thread` synchronisation like detailed [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187235/make-method-that-returns-when-jbutton-is-pressed/14187691#14187691) but you will soon find out that it is a nightmare and that you are not using GUI properly.

Comment: @joeyrohan This is actually quite easy to perform (all you need to do is work with `Thread` synchronization, using `wait()` and `notify()`), but it is a very bad idea. See more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187235/make-method-that-returns-when-jbutton-is-pressed/14187691#14187691

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Ha! I am a dum fellow I can say! Nice answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is not very much clear,but from your comment,you dont want to do any thing till a `JButton` is clicked? Or you want to preform a task after clicking of a button?

If that is so, dont put your further code inside your main block, call a `function` from `actionPerformed` block.Something like this:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // first check all fields aren't empty
     for (JTextField field : nameFields) {
        if (field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
           return ;  // return if empty
        }
     }
     String name = "";
     for (JTextField field : nameFields) {
        name += field.getText() + " ";
        field.setText("");
     }
     name = name.trim();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InputVerifierExample.this, name, "Name Entered",
           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     display();///////////this is the function containing further code
     }
    }
    //this is display
    public void display()
      {
      System.out.println("this line executes...how to prevent..");

      }
```

Comment: i wants only this line execute after clicking button, written in main System.out.println("this line executes...how to prevent.."); like show messagedialog giving option, another line execute only after ok/cancel button, that similar functionality actual wants.

Comment: @user1936089 _"this is simply not how GUI works. To the exception of modal dialogs, GUI are asynchronous and work with callbacks (listeners) such as ActionListener, MouseListener, etc... Don't try to make a Swing GUI synchronous this will bring more problems than solutions."_ suggested by-Guillaume Polet

Comment: can you give me example how to make this asynchronous.please urgent i m integrating some forms in project,

Comment: Me too also integrated.But not like this.Use the code in actionPerformed block,as shown above.What you want to do by the way?

Comment: wait,i'll try to make out something.

Comment: @user1936089 this is the time when i miss goto in java :(

Comment: To Check the functionality showMessageDialog() of JOptionPane i wants as it is. let suppose after wrote 100line after this function while messageDialog is visible on the screen further all line does't execute, till wait ok or cancel button pressing,

Comment: @user1936089 that is what you are looking for.Those line won't execute till the button of `JOptionPane` is pressed.Have you tried out?

Comment: @user1936089 then ? not working for you?If you want to stuck where you want to, catch the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187235/make-method-that-returns-when-jbutton-is-pressed/14187691#14187691) given by -Guillaume Polet